# SQL changing date range into individual rows

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have the following table which I need to make the date range into individual rows. I'm using standard SQL in Big Query.

```
`INSERT INTO my_table (Qty, ID, Source, date_from, date_to)
VALUES
  (null, 101, 'A', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-11'),
  (10, 101, 'A', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-10'),
  (15, 101, 'A', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-08'),
  (null, 101, 'A', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-05'),
  (30, 101, 'A', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-03');``
```

| Qty | ID | Source | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 101 | A | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-11 |
| 10 | 101 | A | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-10 |
| 15 | 101 | A | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-08 |
| null | 101 | A | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-05 |
| 30 | 101 | A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 |

The output should look like this:

| Qty | ID | Source | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 101 | A | 2022/01/01 |
| 30 | 101 | A | 2022/01/02 |
| null | 101 | A | 2022/01/03 |
| null | 101 | A | 2022/01/04 |
| 15 | 101 | A | 2022/01/05 |
| 15 | 101 | A | 2022/01/06 |
| 15 | 101 | A | 2022/01/07 |
| 10 | 101 | A | 2022/01/08 |
| 10 | 101 | A | 2022/01/09 |
| null | 101 | A | 2022/01/10 |

I've been trying a lot of things but the closes get's me duplicate rows when there's a value in Qty.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Qty,
  ID,
  Source
FROM my_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date_to, IF(date_from > CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE(), date_from))) AS date
order by date desc
```

Comment: You are using `IF(date_from > CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE(), date_from)` this condition; But, I do not see any future dates in your data.

Will there be future dates too for `date_from` field ?

Comment: Also,
In Expected output; Is the last record missing ?
`| NULL | 101 | A      | 2022-01-11 |`

Comment: Can you tell me, what will the output if you change only this line as :

`CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date_from, date_to)) AS date`

(Removing `IF` condition) will that return you the expected output ?

Comment: Hey, I saw in some scenarios that it does contain future data, the expected value from the null value is to have that null value or as a 0. Any would satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Ok, In Expected output; Is the last record missing ? `| NULL | 101 | A      | 2022-01-11 |`

Or the expected output is correct ?

Comment: Sorry I want to clarify; the expected output is correct. Following the logic, the date_to is not included so the last date in the output should be 2022-01-10

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```sql
SELECT Qty, ID, Source, date
  FROM my_table, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(date_from), DATE(date_to) - 1)) date
```

- [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) - `start_date` should be prior to `end_date`.
- You can modify `DATE(date_to)` with `IF(date_to > CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE, DATE(date_to) - 1)`

**Query results**

[image]